# Is the imaginary part of $\displaystyle\ \zeta(s)\zeta(1-s)=0$ for $\operatorname{Re}(s)=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function

Some of my computations [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=zeta(s)(zeta(1-s)),+s%3D0.5%2B500i) showed to me that the imaginary part of $\displaystyle\ \zeta(s)\zeta(1-s)=0$ for $\operatorname{Re}(s)=\frac{1}{2}$, really i w'd like to know if there is any paper showed this result that is true for all s with a real part equal's $1/2$.

> > **My question here is:**
> >     Is imaginary part of ($\displaystyle\ \zeta(s)\zeta(1-s))=0$ for $\operatorname{Re}(s) =\frac{1}{2}$ and is there any paper discussed this  ?
>
> **Note:** $ \zeta(s)$  is the Riemann zeta function with $s$ is a complex variable .

Comment: Although the expert answer to the question is "obviously X is true for long-known reasons", the not-quite-experts may be blind-sided by such questions, depending how they approach them... e.g., numerically. Given the small space that it takes to archive such question-and-immediate-answer, it might be worthwhile to keep such things around. As in the fallacy of "it's so clear to experts that they never explain it".

Comment: As a rule, I don't support postings with "i w'd" on this site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\overline{\zeta(s)\zeta(1-s)} = \zeta(\overline{s})\zeta(\overline{1-s}) = \zeta(1-s)\zeta(s)$

($1-s=\overline{s}$ for $Re(s)=1/2$)

So this is indeed a purely real number. $\zeta(\overline{s}) = \overline{\zeta(s)}$ holds because $\overline{\zeta(\overline{s})}-\zeta(s)$ is analytic and zero for real $s>1$, hence zero everywhere.